Understanding how to use constants tables for linear congruential generators (LCGs) from two papers on the internet
I have been reading on https://www.pcg-random.org/pdf/hmc-cs-2014-0905.pdf about how to do some random number generation. It involves LCGs. Exploring on Wikipedia I found out about the following two papers that give reasonable constants for those LCGs:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.05304
https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1999-68-225/S0025-5718-99-00996-5/S0025-5718-99-00996-5.pdf
LCGs are essentially defined by the following relation:
X(n+1) = (a * X(n) + c) mod m, n >= 0.
There are 4 constants involved: m the modulus, a the multiplier, X(0) the starting value or seed and c the increment. The problem is that the LCG constants tables in the papers only give combinations of good m and a. There is no mention about the X(0) and c constants that you need to choose.
Any help in understanding how to choose X(0) and c or mabe me not understanding the papers is much appreciated.

I have emailed Pierre Lecuyer as well to ask about this problem and he
replied exactly with the following points:

m should be a prime number and c=0.  The choice of a is crucial and
not easy.  See the papers.  X(0) can be any number from 1 to m-1.
However, LCGs like that are no longer recommended; they are not
suitable for modern computers because they have too much structure and
their period is too small.

He also gave me 3 references from his papers/books where I may find
what I need, again exactly as he replied:
See chapter 3 of this draft book:
https://www-labs.iro.umontreal.ca/~lecuyer/ift6561/book.pdf
Also here:
https://informs-sim.org/wsc15papers/003.pdf
https://www-labs.iro.umontreal.ca/~lecuyer/myftp/papers/handstat2.pdf
